# Why is my RPi freezing of its own accord?

Tags: pi-3, hardware, lxde

I own a RPi 3 Model B, which does a very good job of freezing of its own accord, even when not much activity is being done.

I mean, I can still move the mouse, but it stays in its last frame and I can't click anything, which forces me to cut the power, which, wastes time.

I haven't put in any code or commands to start this problem, nor have I changed any settings that might affect this (I only update the appearance settings), and even then, my Pi still freezes.

Even when everything looks normal on the actual board.

Oh, and, unlike other questions which have the entire RPi frozen, I can still move the mouse cursor.

I'm also using LXDE 0.9.3 with Stretch repos.

And, I also really don't think this has to do with the GPIO pins because I don't have anything in them!

Even though this might be irrelevant,the only external devices plugged into the Raspberry Pi is a Logitech MX500, a Lenovo keyboard I don't really know about, a Viewsonic VX2640w monitor, and a pair of Labtec speakers I don't really know about either. I'm using the power supply that came out of the box: plugged in through the MircoUSB power supply with an input of 100-240 volts and output of 5.25 volts; 0.45 amps for input and 0.2400 milliamps for output.

In case this might also help, my RPi is known to freeze any time: on an unsaved chromium project, on an unsaved code project, in the middle of a download, right when I'm launching an application, etc.

Thank you.

Comment: How many amps is the power supply rated for? How is connected to the PI (a cheap cable can look like a bad power supply).

Comment: probably 2400 mA, not 0.24 mA. If you have another SD card on hand, try it. I suspect a bad SD here.

Comment: I'll see what I can do

Comment: I'm having this same issue, with a fully up-to-date Raspbian Buster distro.

Comment: Also try another R-Pi if possible. Static damage can be responsible for this kind of thing. (But more likely a power supply being pulled too low due to high current draw.)

Answer (score 1):

Get a speed 10 SD card. I had the EXACT same problem till I got a new SD card. It really helps.

Also, enter `sudo raspi-config`, and change the GPU memory options under `Performance Settings` to `256`.